# ERROR: '~linuxuprising' user or team does not exist

Tags: repository, ubuntu-18.04

I can't add repository on Ubuntu 18.04.

Occur this ERROR: '~linuxuprising' user or team does not exist.

I searched some solutions but the problem persist.
I tried set proxy, reinstall certificates... 
I don't know what to do...

Comment: I discovered the problem, my internet service has any problem, when I used other connection with internet, I could add the repository. I don't know, but I think that my internet service use any proxy or my router is wrong configured.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in my internet service, my ip was in blacklist of the canonical.
I spoke with my internet service and they fix this to me.